# yubikey creating different ssh public key having same GPG

Tags: ssh, gnupg, yubikey

I have 2 yubikeys and both are having the same GPG master key besides 3 subkeys for encrypting, signing and authentication, I can encrypt/decrypt and everything regarding gpg seems to be working fine, the problem is when I am trying to use both keys for login via `ssh`.

Both keys return the same public key when doing:

```
$ gpg --export-ssh bar@foo
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABA...Q== openpgp:0x5867D430
```

When doing `ssh-add -L` only one key returns the same output of the previous command, inded only changes the comment:

```
$ ssh-add -L
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABA...Q== cardno:000605488855
```

But the other key (having the same GPG keys) returns a different key, therefore I can't use it.

The output of `gpg --card-status` including fingerprint's is the same in both keys.

How could I configure (backup) both keys to work with the same ssh public key as in with GPG?